# How do I reference a single table multiple times from a junction table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
contacts table:
----------------------------------------------
| contactId | firstName | lastName | birthday |
----------------------------------------------
```

and

```
birthdayEvents table:
---------------------------------------------
| birthdayEvtId | birthdayPerson | contactee |
---------------------------------------------
```

In the birthdayEvents table, both birthdayPerson and contactee are foreign keys that reference a value of contacts.contactId.

My birthdayEvents table is structured so that one birthdayPerson can have multiple contacts (e.g., these are the people invited to the party)

```
birthdayEvents:
---------------------------------------------
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
---------------------------------------------
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
---------------------------------------------
| 3 | 1 | 4 |
---------------------------------------------
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
---------------------------------------------
| 5 | 2 | 4 |
---------------------------------------------
| 6 | 2 | 5 |
etc...
```

I would like a query that lists the birthday person's name and each contactee's name.  I have tried this

```
SELECT bp.firstName, bp.lastName, c.firstName, c.lastName
FROM contacts AS bp
INNER JOIN birthdayEvents AS be
INNER JOIN contacts AS c
WHERE (bp.contactId = be.birthdayPerson) AND 
(c.contactId = be.contactee)
```

But it does not work, I get a syntax error.  I can't figure out how to write this query.

Comment: [inner join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) requires an `on table1.column_name = table2.column_name` clause

Comment: @userJohn good job on outlining the situation. If i could add one suggestion: when you have a question about a query it's a good thing to include the scripts to create the tables in question and load them with data. that way it's a lot easier for someone trying to get an answer for you to get right to work instead of having to go through the trouble of creating the tables and populating them with data themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You may try joining *twice* to the `contacts` table:

```
SELECT
    b.birthdayEvtId,
    CONCAT(c1.lastName, ', ', c1.firstName) AS birthday_person,
    CONCAT(c2.lastName, ', ', c2.firstName) AS contactee
FROM birthdayEvents b
LEFT JOIN contacts c1
    ON b.birthdayPerson = c1.contactId
LEFT JOIN contacts c2
    ON b.contactee = c2.contactId;
```